# insertBefore in an empty ul

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have a nice, working and functional to-do list. However, in practice (using it on a phone), the new items added to the list are hidden by the keyboard. So I want to have the list add every item to the beginning, or top of the list, so that new items are seen as they are created.

Enter "insertBefore()", which works fine as long as there is a child to insert before, otherwise it throws an error.

How would you have this work with an empty list? Just do an "if there are no child elements, do this - else - do that" or is there a simple addition to the process?

```
var inputText = document.getElementById("textField");
  var myUl = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");

  inputText.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
   if( event.keyCode === 13){
    var myInputText = this.value;
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var spanItem = document.createElement("span");
    var theText = document.createTextNode(myInputText);
    var span_img = document.createElement("img");
    span_img.src = "images/trashCanBlack.png";
    spanItem.appendChild(span_img);
    listItem.appendChild(spanItem);
    listItem.appendChild(theText);

    myUl[0].appendChild(listItem); // this works, but only adds it on the end
    this.value = "";
      }
     });
```

Comment: *"Enter "insertBefore()", which works fine as long as there is a child to insert before, otherwise it throws an error."* ***What*** error? What did your `insertBefore` code look like? `insertBefore` is absolutely fine on an element element, you just give `null` as the reference element (which makes it exactly the same as `appendChild`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to have the list add every item to the beginning, or top of the list...

Believe it or not, it's this easy:

```
myUl[0].insertBefore(listItem, myUl[0].firstChild);
```

It's fine if `myUl[0]` is empty (and thus its `firstChild` is `null`). `insertBefore` is smart enough to handle that (by effectively being `appendChild`).

---

Side note: Rather than doing:

```
var myUl = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
```

...and then using `myUl[0]` everywhere, you might consider either:

```
var myUl = document.querySelector("ul"); // returns the first one
```

or

```
var myUl = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
```

...and then just using `myUl`.

Comment: That worked great. I was fiddling with it but missed the, now obvious, .firstchild bit at the end. And yes, the myUl[0] is a bit tedious so have fixed that too.